# Using openpyxl to find rows that contain cell with specific value

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am completely new to `openpyxl` so, as you can imagine, I am having pretty hard times when I try to make use of it.

I have an Excel report that contains only one sheet (called `Sheet1)`. I'd like to search all cells for those that contain specific string (product name ABC in this case).

Then I would like to copy contents of every cell in the rows that contain cell with `ABC` product name. And assign every cell to a variable.

To give you better idea of what I am trying to achieve I'll give you an example:

[image: Example]

So in this case I would only copy cells from rows: 2, 4, 6 (as only they contain `ABC` product).

I have already looked up similar questions and answers to them but I don't understand them (never have used Excel before).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

is it important for you to use openpyxl to do this? i would suggest using pandas if not.

```
    import pandas as pd

    df = pd.read_excel("path_to_excel_file")
    df_abc = df[df["Products"] == "ABC"] # this will only contain 2,4,6 rows
```

then:

```
    for row in df_abc.iterrows():
        # do what you want with the row
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Pandas solved the problem but now i don't know how to acces single row of those that were selected in the first step. It selected rows 2,4,6 becasue they have ABC product, but now I'd like to get individualy to rows 2, 4, 6 and assigns cells that they contain to variables. Do you have any idea how to approach this step?

Answer (score 34):

There's no need to use the pandas for this.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
import openpyxl

file = "enter_path_to_file_here"
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file, read_only=True)
ws = wb.active

for row in ws.iter_rows("E"):
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value == "ABC":
            print(ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=2).value) #change column number for any cell value you want
```

Answer (score 9):

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook("report.xlsx")
ws = wb.active

for row in ws.rows:
if row[4].value == "ABC":
    for cell in row:
        print(cell.value, end=" ")
    print()
```

Comment: Works as good as first solution. Generates another problem- don't know how to acces selected rows separately.

Answer (score 1):

```
wb = load_workbook("report.xlsx")
ws = wb.active

abc_rows=[]

for row in range(2,ws.max_row+1):
    if(ws[row][4]=='ABC'):
       abc_rows.append(row)
```

To access the selected rows separately, further add this code

```
i=1
abc_dict={}
for row in ws.values:
    if(i in abc_rows):
        (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l)=row
         abc_dict[i]=row
    i=i+1
```

**To access selected rows seperately**, use

> **abc_dict[2]** gives entire second row as tuples and **abc_dict[2][0]** gives
> first cell value. you can parse till **abc_dict[2][11]** to get each cell
> of selected rows seperately.