# Openpyxl - Give cell an identifier

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Rather than iterating until finding a cells coordinates, I'd like to use excel to give cells and rows identifiers that my program can look for. I cant count on a row or cell always being at the same certain coord on all spread sheetsheets so it would be ideal to just search for something like "apple_price" rather than "E5".

```
   wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
            ws = wb.active
            for ws in wb.worksheets:
                for row in ws.iter_rows():
                    for cell in row:
                        print(cell.value)
```

This is just a bit of code that iterates through a workbook and prints the value of each cell. I'd like to iterate though until it found an identifier.

Comment: Like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51801421/9245853)?

Comment: Something like a price isn't always going to be the same every workbook.

Comment: @GTA.sprx You are looking for [defined-names](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/defined_names.html?highlight=named#defined-names)